# How to get the order date from itunes connect account?

Tags: iphone

In my app i want to get the order date when a user purchases any element then his/her itunes account the order date get saved.

How to retrieve this date programtically???

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to In app purchase, then there is a read only property in [SKPaymentTransaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class called as transactionDate.

Comment: hi the problem with my app is when the user try to download the same app which he or she had already purchased fron another device using their itunes account it again asks for purchase.

Comment: So if i will be able to get the order date showing in my itunes account so may be i can resolve this problem.

Comment: If the product is "non consumable", it will only download the product before asking for purchase. The user will get message that the product has already been purchased.